# Constructing an integer with specific totient without factorization

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic, number-theory

Given $N(=pq)$, but not its factorization. Somehow you manage to know, that $k$ divides $\phi(N)$. Is it possible to come up with an integer $N^{*}$, for which $\phi(N^{*})=\phi(N)/k$, without factoring $N$?

Comment: $k$ might be even prime....not sure if it makes the problem easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot @fgrieu! Hint2 seems to be more promising to me, although I'm still stuck. You can multiply/divide?? and add/subtract. I suppose, multiplication is not so useful as it only increases the totient value of an integer. Division does also not seem useful, because if you could divide then it would mean that you know a factor of N. I'm not sure addition or subtraction is useful neither, as totient is multiplicative.

Comment: Since k divides $\phi(N)$ and k is prime, we can say without loss of generality, that k divides $p-1$. This means that $N\equiv q \mod k$. Then I was trying to assume (Dirichlet-theorem) that we can have access to primes with special form, like $kx+/-1$ and alike, but could not proceed much.

Comment: @fgrieu Yes, $N$ has precisely two prime factors $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Hint2a: $gcd(N,N^{*})=gcd(pq,N^{*})$. What do we know about $N^{*}$? Again $k$ divides $p-1$. We know, that $\phi(N^{*})=\phi(N)/k=(p-1)(q-1)/k$, hence $q$ surely divides $N^{*}$ therefore $q$ divides $gcd(N,N^{*})$ as well. I cannot say anything more about (p-1)/k. All I can say, as of now, that  $q$ divides $gcd(N,N^{*})$. I think it cannot be $N$, right? So is it true, that $gcd(N,N^{*})=q$? Can't see why this would help me...knowing  $gcd(N,N^{*})$ feels like equivalent to factoring $N$, what we cannot do by assumption. what am I missing? or is  $gcd(N,N^{*})=N$???

Comment: could you clean up the comments? @fgrieu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remark: $p$ and $q$ are distinct odd primes (if not, we can factor $N$), thus $\phi(N)=(p-1)(q-1)$. Define $p'=(p-1)/2$ and $q'=(q-1)/2$. It holds $\phi(N)=4\,p'\,q'$.

**What's asked is not always possible**. As a counterexample, assume $k=2$ (which is a possible $k$, from above remark), and $p\equiv 3\equiv q\pmod4$ (which covers about 25% of RSA keys). If we could find $N^*$ with $\phi(N^{*})=\phi(N)/k$, it would hold $\phi(N^*)=2\,p'\,q'$ with $p'$ and $q'$ odd. Therefore¹ $N^*$ would be of the form $2^s\,r^t$ with $r$ prime, with $\phi(N^*)=(r-1)\,r^{t-1}$. Therefore we could factor $N^*$, yielding $r$ and $e$, thus $\phi(N^*)$, thus $\phi(N)$, allowing to factor $N$.

Still with $k=2$, $p\equiv3\pmod4$, but this time $q\equiv5\pmod8$ (which covers another about 25% of RSA keys), we have $\phi(N^*)=4\,p'\,q''$ with $p'$ and $q''=(q-1)/4$ odd, and the two possible (non-exclusive) options are²

- that $N^*$ is of the form $2^s\,r^e$ with $r$ prime, which we handle as above.
- that $N^*=(2\,p'+1)\,(2\,q''+1)$ with $(2\,p'+1)$ and $(2\,q''+1)$ distinct primes, in which case $N^*=p\,((q+1)/2)$, thus $\gcd(N,N^*)$ will be $p$, yielding a factorization of $N$.

More generally, if what is asked was possible, there is some chance that at least one of the following holds:

- $\gcd(N,N^*)$ reveals a factor of $N$.
- we can factor $N^*$ (including but not limited to $N^*=2^s\,r^t$), then can compute $\phi(N^*)$, thus $\phi(N)$, allowing us to factor $N$.

I have a feeling that's a fair chance for random $N$ when $k$ is small.

Independently: When $k$ is large, and especially when it is prime, it's value is revealing: it must divide $p-1$ or $q-1$, thus $\gcd(N,j\,k+1)$ will be $p$ or $q$ for some $j$, and it is worth trying to find $j$ by enumeration at least when $\sqrt N/k$ is small enough and there is no reason to believe that $\max(p,q)/\min(p,q)$ is large.

When $k$ has a large prime factor $k'$ that we can find, that $k'$ must divide $p-1$ or $q-1$, and we may be able to use the same approach to factor $N$. And with a bit of luck, the product $k'\,k''$ where $k''$ is a large factor of $k/k'$ will divide $p-1$ or $q-1$, allowing to factor $N$. And even if we can't fully factor $k$, because the largest factor we find is composite, it  still has a fair chance to divide $p-1$ or $q-1$, allowing to factor $N$.

---

I vaguely conjecture (would not bet the house) that there are vanishingly few semiprimes $N$ such that an oracle knowing its factorization could reveal $k$, $N^*$ as in the question without the combination of the above techniques being of great help to factor $N$. In other words, what's asked would demonstrably be impossible for overwhelmingly most $N$.

---

¹ This uses the following lemma: if $\phi(m)\equiv2\pmod4$, then $m$ is of the form $2^s\,r^t$ with $r$ prime. Proof of that lemma can be by contraposition using the expression of Euler's totient: $$\phi\left(\prod_{p_i\text{ distinct primes}} {p_i}^{e_i}\right)=\prod_{\text{same }(p_i,e_i)}(p_i-1)\,{p_i}^{(e_i-1)}$$

² This is left as an exercise to the reader, using the same kind of argument as for the above lemma.

Comment: Merci @fgrieu! Why do you conclude in the second to the last line of your answer that $N$ must be of the form $r^{e}$, where $r$ is prime? I could not follow that conclusion. How is it following from $\Phi(N^*)$ being $2\,p'\,q'$?

Comment: Woah! Super-quality answer! Thanks a lot @fgrieu! You gave a lot of insights here! A lot of food for thought! So, the takeaway message from this question is that, If I can understand your points correctly, in case of most $N$, if this would be possible, then one could factor $N$ as well.

Comment: @IstvánAndrásSeres: yes!